# TFS.exe command line doesn't appear to redirect all output to a file when told to

Tags: tfs, command-line-arguments

Background:
We have a build machine that gets from TFS and builds projects and a number of installations (including Installshield).
I want to scan the output of a TFS get command to highlight any local file errors or warnings during that process.

Problem:
When using

```
tf.exe get /force /recursive >>mylogfile.txt
```

I get a wonderfully large log file of the successful items, but at the end it says

```
---- Summary: 0 conflicts, 0 warnings, 1 errors ----
```

The errors appear to be missing from the contents of the log file, but are present in the command line window.

Is there any way I can make the tf.exe output all of it's warnings and errors to my log file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
tf.exe get /force /recursive 1> mylogfile.txt 2>&1
```

tf.exe outputs errors on the STDERR stream, whereas the default redirection only captures the STDOUT stream, leaving the STDERR in the command prompt (which is why you don't see the errors). The syntax above redirects STDERR into STDOUT, then STDOUT into a file.

Comment: Thanks (both of you) I had no idea this functionality existed.

Answer (score 3):

How about redirecting stderr along with stdio?

```
tf get /force /r > mylogfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, you were just beaten by Russ by 1 min :-)